# Find the minimum bandwidth that can be used octave

Tags: matlab, octave, bandwidth

i should find the minimum bandwidth that can be used for the song to still be distinguishable by a listener

and this is my code so far

```
% A.Read the song and assign vules

[y, fs] = wavread('Dog Woof.wav');

time = (1:length(y))/30000;
plot(time, y); % ploting the sin wave of the song
title('Sound waves');
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Frequency');

% B.Simple rate will be the fs value
fs

% C.Bandwidth

[UPPER, LOWER] = bandwidth(y)
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of the [Nyquist Sampling Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem#Introduction)?

Comment: What do you do to minimize the bandwidth of your signal? Physically the minimum bandwidth to be distinguished from background sound is depending on the spectrum of this particular background sound. The function `bandwidth` does something completely different. It determines the number of diagonals in a matrix that contain values different from 0.